# Divs not lining up in Bootstrap Container class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: original image]

[image: my attempt]

Hi Everyone,

I am trying to achieve the affect shown in [original image] where the "browse collection" div and the "request brochure" div line up with the four items above them.

I am trying to achieve the effect by using bootstrap and thought putting the elements in bootstraps "container" class would make everything line up. I haven't managed to get it to work yet though and the right sides don't line up.  Can someone suggest a solution please?  below is my code. thank you!

```css
body {

 font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
 
}

/* content Area 2 */

 .contentarea2{
  background-color: #e3e2da;
  width: 100%;
  height: 585px;
  position: relative;
 }

 .squares{
  padding-top: 120px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
 .optionswrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px; 
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
 }
 
 .option1{
  width: 50%;
  height: 75px; 
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  float: left;
 }
 
 .option2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 75px; 
  background-color: #9b998f;
  float: right;
 }

/* buttons */

.collection {
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: Transparent;
 padding: 10px;
}

.collection:hover{
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #3d3d3d;
 padding: 10px;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* animations */
   
.fade2 {
   opacity: 1;
   -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
   }
   
      .fade2:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      }

.overlay-portfolio{
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:100;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
    <title>container</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <!-- Custom CSS -->
 <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <!-- fonts -->
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
 </head>
  <body>
 
 <div class="contentarea2">
 
  <div class="container squares">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 triangles">
 
     <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive fade2" src="img/square1.jpg" alt="client 1"></a>
     
     <div class="overlay-portfolio">
     <h3>Modern</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 triangles">
     <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive fade2" src="img/square2.jpg" alt="client 1"></a>
     <div class="overlay-portfolio">
     <h3>Contemporary</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 triangles">
     <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive fade2" src="img/square3.jpg" alt="client 1"></a>
     <div class="overlay-portfolio">
     <h3>Minimalist</h3>
     </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 triangles">
     <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive fade2" src="img/square4.jpg" alt="client 1"></a>
     <div class="overlay-portfolio">
     <h3>Classic</h3>
     </div>
    
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="optionswrapper">
   <div class="option1">
   </div>
   
   <div class="option2">
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 
 </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're after, but you should only modify grid elements as a last resort (use child elements instead), and putting 100% width on everything just makes for headaches. Here's a start. What's it supposed to look like? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/mzcqekL0

Comment: Maybe this is closer. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/mzcqekL0/2/

Comment: Z-index fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/mzcqekL0/3

Comment: thanks for the advice and the suggested solution, however its not quite what I am looking for.  I want the two .option1 and .option2 to be at the bottom of the .contentarea2 class and not fixed to the bottom of the page because there will be other divs/sections above and below .contentarea2.  Please see here for the effect I am going for: http://imgur.com/XxeFjU8

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline class' from your squares and add the class `col-xs-height col-top`

and replace row container with `row-same-height`

that should put them all into proportion.